# How to add variable to store getters vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, store, getter

I can't figure out how to add/join variable to store getters in vueJS. When I try to do this then it tells me that categorySlug is never used

```
return this.$store.getters.addedProducts.categorySlug
```

My current code

```
myValue () {
  const anyVariableName = this.$store.getters.categorySlug
  return this.$store.getters.addedProducts.anyVariableName
}
```

Comment: "When I try to do this then it tells me that categorySlug is never used" - who tells and how? If there's an error or warning, it needs to be listed.The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. It's unknown how this.$store.getters.categorySlug and this.$store.getters.addedProducts.categorySlug are related.

Comment: Read the error carefully, it's litterally describing the problem: you are creating the `categorySlug` variable, but you never use it. Just do `return categorySlug`.

Comment: I changed the typo but that's not the issue. I want to use variable inside store getter path to join them together.

Comment: He must looking for this `this.$store.getters.addedProducts[anyVariableName]`

Comment: Yes you're a legend Naren. That is what I was looking for.
     const anyVariableName = this.categorySlug
      return this.addedProducts[anyVariableName][0].id

Comment: You can add your answer as a comment so I can confirm it.